# Check if image is monochromatic

Tags: .net, image-processing

I need to have a quick way to check whether image of monochromatic or not. I mean I need to verify that the image contains just a single color (black, white, red square...) instead of containing multiple colors.

Of course, I can compare all pixels of image with first, but it can be slow. Any another way to check it?

Comment: How do you plan on handling a single white pixel in a random position within a black square?

Comment: Please provide more information on which image formats should be supported and which .net class you are using to read the images

Comment: Do you mean monochromatic?

Comment: JPEG (mostly), PNG, BMP

Comment: Do you really mean uniform images, all pixels the same color value ? Unless the image is palletized, you must look at all pixels. For the JPEG format, you can work in the compressed domain, check that the blocks are uniform and all of the same color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your definition of slow.  I am finding that it takes about 12 ms to scan a 1MP image if all pixels need to be evaluated, and significantly shorter (nanoseconds in most cases, since the first and second pixels are different) on a random sampling of images.

Test code (Core i5 on W8.1 x64, compiled with `/unsafe /platform:x64` on .Net 4.5):

```
private unsafe bool CheckBitmapIsMonotonic(Bitmap newBitmap)
{
    var data = newBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, newBitmap.Size),
        ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    try
    {
        byte* pixelData = (byte*)data.Scan0.ToPointer();
        uint firstPixelData = *((uint*)pixelData);

        for (int row = 0; row < data.Height; row++)
        {
            uint* cRowPointer = (uint*)(pixelData + data.Stride * row);

            for (int column = 0; column < data.Width; column++)
            {
                var rgbPixelValue = cRowPointer[column];

                if (firstPixelData != rgbPixelValue)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        newBitmap.UnlockBits(data);
    }
}
```

This is just a first pass.  You may be able to squeeze some extra performance by moving to `ulong` rather than `uint` and compare two pixels at once, and if you can avoid the conversion to `ARGB`, all the better.

Answer (score 1):

This highly depends on the image formats you would like to support (PNG, BMP, etc).

For instance, if the image uses a color palette (some types of PNG do), you could check if the palette has only one color entry. (see System.Drawing.Image.Palette).

But in general, you will probably have to check every pixel to make sure.

Comment: This only works for palettes if the palette is actually optimized to have only the colors used in the image. It's possible to have paletted images with more entries than colors used. (It's not very frequent, though.)